# Subida multiple de archivos por AJAX y problema con post_max_size

Tags: jquery, ajax

Buenas tardes!
Estoy creando una subida de archivos múltiple con jQuery/AJAX y PHP.
Haciendo pruebas, me he dado cuenta de que cuando selecciono un total de +3mb de archivos, no me hace el upload. Cuando es menos de eso sí lo hace.

He mirado mi phpinfo y he visto que el parametro upload_max_filesize es de 64M, pero mirando más, he visto que el parámetro post_max_size es de 3M. Creo que ese es el problema, que al subirlo con POST mi server compara con post_max_size en vez de upload_max_filesize.

Si no quiero cambiar el parámetro post_max_size... ¿cómo puedo hacer la petición AJAX para que lo tome como una subida de archivos en vez de un POST?

```
function subir_adjuntos_licencia(){
    //Creamos un objeto formData
    var fd = new FormData();
    //fd.append("estado", $("#selestados option:selected").val());
    for (var i=0, len=document.getElementById('adjuntos_licencia').files.length; i< len; i++) 
    {
        fd.append("adjuntos_licencia"+i , document.getElementById('adjuntos_licencia').files[i]);
    }
    //Petición AJAX           
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?= site_url('admin/licencias/detalle_licencia_usuario/subir_adjuntos_licencia_usuario?ins='.$institucion_id.'&lic='.$id_licencia);?>",
        type: "POST",
        data : fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if(data.error == false)
            {
                $("#adjuntos_licencia").fileinput('clear');
                toastr.success(data.mensaje);
            }
            else
            {
                 toastr.error(data.mensaje);
            }

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             toastr.error(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿cómo puedo hacer la petición AJAX para que lo tome como una subida de archivos en vez de un POST?

Creo que te estás confundiendo, una cosa no está relacionada con la otra.

`POST` es simplemente uno de los métodos definidos para comunicaciones HTTP. Es básicamente una "clave" para indicar que el mensaje modificará datos en el servidor.

Que el contenido del mensaje sean los datos de un formulario, o attachments (ficheros), o cualquier otra cosa, no afecta a que el mensaje sea `POST` o no. Tampoco que la petición sea Ajax o no, que el cliente sea un navegador o no, etc...

> Creo que ese es el problema, que al subirlo con POST mi server compara con post_max_size en vez de upload_max_filesize.

Debería compararlo con los dos. El `post_max_size` verifica el tamaño del mensaje HTTP, el `upload_max_filesize` el tamaño de los distintos ficheros.

Por poner una analogía, es como si envias artículos en un paquete por correo. En la oficina de correos comprobarán si el paquete que envías cumple con los límites válidos para el paquete, una vez llegue el paquete a destino y lo abrán quien lo reciba comprobará si lo que está dentro del paquete les vale.

Veo tres alternativas:

- Modificar post_file_size solo para esas URLs. Por desgracia [según esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806459/php-specific-function-url-file-max-post-size) parece que tendrías que poner el valor máximo para todo el sitio y, donde quieras un valor menor, hacer las comprobaciones en el PHP.
- Usar PUT: Tendrás que [configurar el servidor](http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.put-method.php). Y tendrás que [montarte tú el mensaje](http://www.claindsilva.com/web-development/ajax-file-upload-with-http-put-method-using-php-and-jquery/) (nada de que el navegador te separe los distintos ficheros, te meta los valores de los parámetros, etc.) y procesarlo; recomiendo usar una llamada diferente para cada fichero.
- Sacar la comunicación de archivos de HTTP y usar un WebSocket. Parece complicado, y no creo que merezca la pena.

Comment: Me resignaré y cambiaré el valor =(